# Problems With AndroidManifes xml. App force closes on run

Tags: java, android

Hey guys I'm pretty new to android. I thought that a good idea for a first app would be a calculator. I created that app completely it installs and compiles correctly. But when I go to run it on my device it force closes. I think there may be an issue in my AndroidManifest.xml file but I don't know what it is.

This is may java code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.awesomeapps.misael.simplecalculator.R;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{
    Button one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, zero, add, sub, mul, div, cancel, equal;
    EditText disp;
    int op1;
    int op2;
    String optr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_main);

        one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.one);
        two = (Button) findViewById(R.id.two);
        three = (Button) findViewById(R.id.three);
        four = (Button) findViewById(R.id.four);
        five = (Button) findViewById(R.id.five);
        six = (Button) findViewById(R.id.six);
        seven = (Button) findViewById(R.id.seven);
        eight = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eight);
        nine = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nine);
        zero = (Button) findViewById(R.id.zero);
        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
        sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sub);
        mul = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mul);
        div = (Button) findViewById(R.id.div);
        cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel);
        equal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.equal);

        disp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

        try {
            one.setOnClickListener(this);
            two.setOnClickListener(this);
            three.setOnClickListener(this);
            four.setOnClickListener(this);
            five.setOnClickListener(this);
            six.setOnClickListener(this);
            seven.setOnClickListener(this);
            eight.setOnClickListener(this);
            nine.setOnClickListener(this);
            zero.setOnClickListener(this);
            cancel.setOnClickListener(this);
            add.setOnClickListener(this);
            sub.setOnClickListener(this);
            mul.setOnClickListener(this);
            div.setOnClickListener(this);
            equal.setOnClickListener(this);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    public void operation() {
        if (optr.equals("+")) {
            op2 = Integer.parseInt(disp.getText().toString());
            disp.setText("");
            op1 = op1 + op2;
            disp.setText("Result: " + Integer.toString(op1));
        } else if (optr.equals("-")) {
            op2 = Integer.parseInt(disp.getText().toString());
            disp.setText("");
            op1 = op1 - op2;
            disp.setText("Result" + Integer.toString(op1));
        } else if (optr.equals("*")) {
            op2 = Integer.parseInt(disp.getText().toString());
            disp.setText("");
            op1 = op1 * op2;
            disp.setText("Result" + Integer.toString(op1));
        } else if (optr.equals("/")) {
            op2 = Integer.parseInt(disp.getText().toString());
            disp.setText("");
            op1 = op1 / op2;
            disp.setText("Result" + Integer.toString(op1));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Editable str = disp.getText();
        switch (arg0.getId()) {
            case R.id.one:
                if (op2 != 0) {
                    op2 = 0;
                    disp.setText("");
                }
                str = str.append(two.getText());
                disp.setText(str);
                break;
            case R.id.two:
                if (op2 != 0) {
                    op2 = 0;
                }
                str = str.append(two.getText());
                disp.setText(str);
            case R.id.three:
                if (op2 != 0) {
                    op2 = 0;
                }
                str = str.append(three.getText());
                disp.setText(str);
                break;
            case R.id.four:
                if (op2 != 0) {
                    op2 = 0;
                }
                str = str.append(four.getText());
                disp.setText(str);
                break;
            case R.id.five:
                if (op2 != 0) {
                    op2 = 0;
                }
                str = str.append(five.getText());
                disp.setText(str);
                break;
            case R.id.six:
                if (op2 != 0) {
                    op2 = 0;
                }
                str = str.append(six.getText());
                disp.setText(str);
                break;
            case R.id.seven:
                if (op2 != 0) {
                    op2 = 0;
                }
                str = str.append(eight.getText());
                disp.setText(str);
                break;
            case R.id.eight:
                if (op2 != 0) {
                    op2 = 0;
                }
                str = str.append(nine.getText());
                disp.setText(str);
                break;
            case R.id.nine:
                if (op2 != 0) {
                    op2 = 0;
                }
                str = str.append(zero.getText());
                disp.setText(str);
                break;
            case R.id.cancel:
                op1 = 0;
                op2 = 0;
                disp.setText("");
                disp.setHint("Perform Operation");
                break;
            case R.id.add:
                optr = "+";
                if (op1 == 0) {
                    op1 = Integer.parseInt(disp.getText().toString());
                    disp.setText("");
                } else if (op2 != 0) {
                    op2 = 0;
                    disp.setText("");
                } else {
                    op2 = Integer.parseInt(disp.getText().toString());
                    disp.setText("");
                    op1 = op1 + op2;
                    disp.setText("Result" + Integer.toString(op1));
                }
                break;
            case R.id.sub:
                optr = "-";
                if (op1 == 0) {
                    op1 = Integer.parseInt(disp.getText().toString());
                    disp.setText("");
                } else if (op2 != 0) {
                    op2 = 0;
                    disp.setText("");
                } else {
                    op2 = Integer.parseInt(disp.getText().toString());
                    disp.setText("");
                    op1 = op1 - op2;
                    disp.setText("Result" + Integer.toString(op1));
                }
                break;
            case R.id.mul:
                optr = "*";
                if (op1 == 0) {
                    op1 = Integer.parseInt(disp.getText().toString());
                    disp.setText("");
                } else if (op2 != 0) {
                    op2 = 0;
                    disp.setText("");
                } else {
                    op2 = Integer.parseInt(disp.getText().toString());
                    disp.setText("");
                    op1 = op1 * op2;
                    disp.setText("Result" + Integer.toString(op1));
                }
                break;
            case R.id.div:
                optr = "/";
                if (op1 == 0) {
                    op1 = Integer.parseInt(disp.getText().toString());
                    disp.setText("");
                } else if (op2 != 0) {
                    op2 = 0;
                    disp.setText("");
                } else {
                    op2 = Integer.parseInt(disp.getText().toString());
                    disp.setText("");
                    op1 = op1 / op2;
                    disp.setText("Result" + Integer.toString(op1));
                }
                break;
            case R.id.equal:
                if (optr.equals(null)) {
                    if (op2 != 0) {
                        if (optr.equals("+")) {
                            disp.setText("");
                    /*op1 = op1+op2;*/
                            disp.setText("Result:" + Integer.toString(op1));
                        } else if (optr.equals("-")) {
                            disp.setText("");/*
                    op1 = op1 - op2;*/
                            disp.setText("Result" + Integer.toString(op1));
                        } else if (optr.equals("*")) {
                            disp.setText("");/*
                    op1 = op1*op2;*/
                            disp.setText("Result" + Integer.toString(op1));
                        } else if (optr.equals("/")) {
                            disp.setText("");/*
                    op1=op1/op2;*/
                            disp.setText("Result" + Integer.toString(op1));
                        }
                    } else {
                        operation();
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my AndroidManifest xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.awesomeapps.misael.simplecalculator">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Oh also I get this error message:

```
05-29 21:48:03.091 10728-10728/com.awesomeapps.misael.simplecalculator E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.awesomeapps.misael.simplecalculator, PID: 10728
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.awesomeapps.misael.simplecalculator/com.awesomeapps.misael.simplecalculator.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.awesomeapps.misael.simplecalculator.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.awesomeapps.misael.simplecalculator-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2641)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2855)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:181)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1474)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6117)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.awesomeapps.misael.simplecalculator.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.awesomeapps.misael.simplecalculator-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1079)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2631)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2855) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:181) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1474) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6117) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194) 
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.awesomeapps.misael.simplecalculator.MainActivity
at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

If anyone could please help by telling me what to fix in either my java code or android manifest xml file. Or maybe its something completely different.

Any help would be awesome and very much appreciated! Thank You! :)

Comment: There is no `package com.awesomeapps.misael.simplecalculator;` in your  activity class.

Comment: What is the name of package has `MainActivity` class? I guess you put not correct package.

Comment: Add package and remove ```import com.awesomeapps.misael.simplecalculator.R;```

Comment: Clean the project > restart the IDE > and rebuild your project

Answer (score 0):

Add below line at the top of your **MainActivity**  class:

```
package com.awesomeapps.misael.simplecalculator;
```

After this clean and Rebuild your project.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to run your code and pasted everything into new project. What I did next is that:

1) removed this

```
import com.awesomeapps.misael.simplecalculator.R;
```

2) imported my package to the first line of MainActivity.java (which is in your case I guess is)

```
package com.awesomeapps.misael.simplecalculator;
```

I haven't touched manifest file. Then it turns out to run without any errors.

However, I should mention that there are a lot of **bugs** in your code. At least, it didn't show the results and some number buttons enter incorrect value when you press them. Run through code and fix bugs. Finally, it would be great if you included some textview to your layout that would explain how to use your calculator. Happy coding :)

Comment: I tried what you did and it says oacke R does not exist.

Comment: @AmateurProgrammer  Did you included the package name at the very top? It should be on the first line of MainActivity.java

Comment: I had a huge typo in my package line and in my activity name line in XML file but I finally did it it works! Now I know I have a lot of bugs to fix lol thanks for all your help! :D

Comment: I figured it out I had huge typos n my package name line and in my XML file thank you for all your help! Now to fix some bugs lol :)

Comment: @AmateurProgrammer Is it working properly now? Did you managed to fix all bugs?

Answer (score 0):

add package name to the MainActivity

```
package com.awesomeapps.misael.simplecalculator;
```

Delete this line `import com.awesomeapps.misael.simplecalculator.R;`

delete build folder 
clean and rebuild your project. Hope it will solve your problem.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to enable multi-dex in your project then just go to gradle.builder

and add this in your dependencie

```
    dependencies {
      compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'}
```

then you have to add

```
    defaultConfig {
     ...
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 21
    ...

    // Enabling multidex support.
       multiDexEnabled true}
```

Then open a class and extand it to Application If your app uses extends the Application class, you can override the oncrete() method and call.

```
     //add this code into your application class
public class MyApplication extends Application {
       // public Context context;
@Override
public void onCreate( ) {
    super.onCreate();
  }
}
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(newBase);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

to enable multidex.

and finally add into your manifest

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
   <application
   ...
   android:name=".MyApplication"">
   ...
  </application>
  </manifest>
```

Comment: i also get same error(classNotFoundException),add this code, worked fine

Comment: I'm using Android studio I don't really know where to go do the changes